# TeamCity Plugin Development Maven

Tags: servlets, teamcity, maven-plugin

So I'm tying to develop a very simple TeamCity Plugin. The Plugin is just suppose to take user input and display it. My code seems to work on my local Tomcat server but when i try to integrate it into TeamCity via the Basecontroller class from jetbrains there seems to be no output. This is my code

```
public class AppServer extends BaseController{

private PluginDescriptor myDescriptor;

public AppServer (WebControllerManager manager, PluginDescriptor descriptor) {
    manager.registerController("/demoPlugin.html",this);
    myDescriptor=descriptor;
}


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse responseone)throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            responseone.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = responseone.getWriter();

            try {
                out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                out.println("<html><head>");
                out.println("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");
                out.println("<title>Echo Servlet</title></head>");
                out.println("<body><h2>You have enter</h2>");

                String requirement = request.getParameter("requirement");
                if (requirement == null || (requirement = htmlFilter(requirement.trim())).length() == 0) {
                    out.println("<p>Agent Requirement: Not specified</p>");
                }
                else {
                    out.println("<p>Agent Requirement: " + requirement + "</p>");

                }
                out.println("<a href='form_input.html'>BACK</a>");
                out.println("</body></html>");
            }
            finally{
                out.close();  
            }
        } 
         finally{
                return;
            }
}

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse responseone)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
            doGet(request, responseone);
    }

private static String htmlFilter(String message) {
    if (message == null) return null;
    int len = message.length();
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(len + 20);
    char aChar;

   for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        aChar = message.charAt(i);
        switch (aChar) {
            case '<': result.append("&lt;"); break;
            case '>': result.append("&gt;"); break;
            case '&': result.append("&amp;"); break;
            case '"': result.append("&quot;"); break;
            default: result.append(aChar);
        }
    }
  return (result.toString());
   }
       protected ModelAndView doHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 

    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception {
            return new ModelAndView(myDescriptor.getPluginResourcesPath("Hello.jsp"));
        }
    }
```

I honestly don't know what I'm doing and I cannot seem to find any good tutorials regarding Basecontroller class from jetbrains. Please help.

Comment: You can get inspired by a number of [examples](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=jetbrains+%22extends+BaseController%22&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93). What exactly doesn't work? I would suggest to try to debug the plugin. Also check whether it was really loaded.

Comment: The plugin successfully integrates into my TeamCity server. It displays the user input page but when i submit something i get a HTTP Status 404 - /echo error. This is a really dumb question but how do i debug the plugin?

Comment: [This](https://jaketrent.com/post/debugging-remote-tomcat-intellij/) or [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Development+Environment) might help you. You have to run Tomcat with remote debug (extra command line params) and then configure run configuration to connect to remote debug port (usually 5005). After that you should be able to put breakpoints in your code.